# Using 2 factor authentication with Azure Ad b2c and the authenticator App

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Can i use the 2FA with the Microsoft Authenticator App on Azure ADb2c ?

The documentation does not seem to have any thing about that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not currently.

But you can generate an [OTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/one-time-password-technical-profile) if that helps?

Comment: Is there a plan to have that in the future?

Comment: I believe it's on the roadmap.

Comment: Here is the sample code. https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-mfa-totp